# Squeeze Theorem on Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading a proof on the Squeeze Theorem related to Riemann integrals...the squeeze theorem states : Let $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow R$ .Then $f\in R[a,b]$ if and only if for every $ \epsilon>0$ there exist function $\alpha_{\epsilon}$ and $\omega_{\epsilon}$ in $R[,a,b]$ with $\alpha_{\epsilon}(x)\leq f(x)\leq \omega_{\epsilon}$ for all $x\in[a,b]$,such that $\int^{b}_{a}(\omega_{\epsilon}-\alpha_{\epsilon})<\epsilon $ .
I did not really get the part why did we assume the equality case $\alpha_{\epsilon}=\omega_{\epsilon}=f$ and proceeded with it...I mean if we assume this and proceed then it stands out the theorem is valid only for this equality case and not for the other cases.
Now the proof is given as

> Proof: Take $\alpha_{\epsilon}=\omega_{\epsilon}=f$ for all $\epsilon >0$.
> Let $\epsilon>0$ .Since $\alpha_{\epsilon}$ and $\alpha_{\epsilon}$ belong to $R[a,b]$ ,there exists any tagged partition with $||\dot{P}||<\delta_{\epsilon}$ then $|S(\alpha_{\epsilon};\dot{P})-\int^{b}_{a}\alpha_{\epsilon}|<\epsilon $ and $|S(\omega_{\epsilon};\dot{P})-\int^{b}_{a}\omega_{\epsilon}|<\epsilon$ . It follows from these inequalities that $\int^{b}_{a}\alpha_{\epsilon}-\epsilon<S(\alpha_{\epsilon};\dot{P})$ and $S(\omega_{\epsilon};\dot{P})<\int_{a}^{b}\omega_{\epsilon} +\epsilon$ In view of the given inequality ,we have $S(\alpha_{\epsilon};\dot{P})\leq S(f_{\epsilon};\dot{P})\leq S(\omega_{\epsilon};\dot{P})$ ,whence $\int^{a}_{b}\alpha_{\epsilon}-\epsilon<S(f;\dot{P})<\int^{a}_{b}\alpha_{\epsilon}+\epsilon$ If $\dot{Q}$ is another tagged partition with $||\dot{Q}||$ ,then we also have $\int^{a}_{b}\omega_{\epsilon}-\epsilon<S(f;\dot{P})<\int^{a}_{b}\omega_{\epsilon}+\epsilon$
> If we subtract these two inequalities ,we get$S(f;\dot{P})-S(f,\dot{Q})|<\int^{a}_{b}\omega_{\epsilon}-\int^{a}_{b}\alpha_{\epsilon}+2\epsilon=\int^{a}_{b}(\omega_{\epsilon}-\alpha_{\epsilon})+2\epsilon<3\epsilon$ .Since $\epsilon>0$,the Cauchy Criterion implies $f\in R[a,b]$.

Comment: The first sentence is nonsensical. Where did you find this proof? The third sentence also has an obvious typo and makes little sense. Are you translating from some other language?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin are u talking about the solutions first sentence or my query's first sentence...if you are talking about the solutions first sentence then I  cannot help it as I typed what was written ( as it is) ....

Comment: The solutions. Throw that out and revise a bit, and it seems then a valid approach.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I dont know about that ...its okay with the first line at least it seems okay to me ... they are considering three functions $\alpha_{\epsilon}(x)=f(x)=\omega_{\epsilon}(x)$ ...i think they have basically represented those functions by their names i.e.$\alpha_{\epsilon}=f(x)=\omega_{\epsilon}$...and can you please say me how the approach is valid in sense...i mean they basically considered the equality conditions of these functions and proved the result whereas the result must also hold true for the following  inequality i.e. $\alpha_{\epsilon}\leq f(x)\leq\omega_{\epsilon}$...

Comment: Taking them equal to $f$ is nonsense. They are to be Riemann-integrable and we must prove $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Exactly ...that's what I am talking about we can never take them equal or so...it really does not make any sense as then the proof will imply that the result is only valid for the equality cases ...so the proof is not correct according to me...This is not quite a  valid approach...that's why I posted this in order to check the validity of this method.....